# Use QProcess to Start Another exe and Generated file with Wrong Path

Tags: c++, qt

I met a question recently. I use `QProcess` class to start `B.exe` in `A.pro`. The absolutely path of `A.pro` is `C:/QT/A/A.pro`. I use `windeployqt` to package `B.exe`, and put the package folder in `C:/QT/A/B/B.exe`.

In `B.exe`, the program will generate a file named `test.json`. The `test.json`'s path is the same as `B.exe`. But I use follows codes in `A.pro`, the `test.json` is generated to the path the same as  `A.pro` but not in folder `C:/QT/A/B`:

`bool f = QProcess::startDetached("./B/B.exe");`

The line code return `true`. I think `test.json` should generated in folder `C:/QT/A/B` but not in `C:/QT/A`. When I double click `B.exe` standlone, it can generate correctly. But when I debug with code above in `A.pro`, it works failed and it just created a empty file.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into [QProcess::startDetached](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-1), it reads as follows:

> The process will be started in the directory workingDirectory. If
> workingDirectory is empty, the working directory is inherited from the
> calling process.

You need to set working directory for `QProcess`. When you run B.exe by "double clicking" it. Your OS sets the working dir from where it was started, i.e, `C:/QT/A/B`. But when you start it from A.exe, its working directory is `C:/QT/A/`

You can read about QProcess::setWorkingDirectory [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setWorkingDirectory). But since, you are running it with QProcess::startDetached overload, you just need to pass wanted working directory as a parameter:

```
bool f = QProcess::startDetached("./B/B.exe", QStringList(), "./B/");
```

Comment: It works for me. I ignored that the process's working directory is inherited from the calling process if  param `workingDirectory` is empty. That's the reason why `test.json` is generated in `C:/QT/A/`. Thank you very much.